# Vacuum space has mass/energy?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, mass-energy, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

It is said that vacuum spaces contain particles and antiparticles, my question is if so whether empty space has mass/energy?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy

Answer (score 0):

Space/Time has "mass". In fact the mass causes "viscosity" around the planets.This is what made Einstein say that Space/Time is curved.The truth is that
Gravity is the balance of forces between two bodies.
The most important forces are those internal forces that cause the body to rotate.Einstein was wrong about Space/Time though.It doesn't direct the body to move.The Earth revolves around the Sun because of the internal forces guiding it to rotate.